navigation.goBack() not working in expo 52
I upgraded my expo react native app from expo sdk 51 to sdk 52
Fixed some minor errors but one came up and I cannot find the solution anywhere.
<NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={
              storedCredentials ? "ErrandLandingScreen" : "OnboardingScreen"
            }
            screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
              headerShown: false,
              headerShadowVisible: false,
              headerTitle: "",
              headerTitleAlign: "center",
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: colors.white,
                paddingHorizontal: 20,
              },
              animation: "fade",
              headerLeft: (props) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  {...props}
                  onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
                  
                >
                  <Ionicons name="chevron-back-outline" size={23} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ),
            })}
          >
    //screens go here
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

Above is my code. But the navigation.goBack() is not working again after the upgrade.
Please help

Actually it turns out the headerleft or headerright just isn't clickable again
That is why it does not work

Do you know how to fix the header not clickable problem?

headerLeft and headerRight is clickable, but it does not work. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/32927

Try using router.back() instead
import {router} from "expo-router";

Thank you for replying. However I'm not using expo router
I'm using @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/native-stack
